# Files too big for GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my Xcode project to GitHub. What I have done so far is followed the usual steps to upload to GitHub ie..

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/Repository_Name.git
git push -u origin master
```

I then get these errors:

```
remote: warning: File Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox is 90.20 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
```

and

```
remote: error: File Pods/MapboxNavigationNative/MapboxNavigationNative.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MapboxNavigationNative is 303.07 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

So what I did was I removed the Pod folder as it can be reinatalled after cloning using:

```
git rm -r Pods
```

This worked but I am still getting the same errors

Please tell me where I am going wrong :)

Here is a pic of the errors:

[image]

Comment: You can either: not check in pods/dependencies, and rely on CocoaPods to fetch them for you on-request, or use Git LFS https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: thanks for answering @Alexander I tried using LFS but it wouldnt accept my POD folder in the gitAttributes ...

Comment: "but it wouldnt accept my POD folder in the gitAttributes ... " what does that mean, exactly?

Comment: When I ran  " git lfs track 'Pods' " it never added the folder

Comment: Add `Pods` directory in `.gitignore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the `Pods` folder to a file called `.gitignore` that must be placed at the root of your project (where the `.git` folder can be find).

To add it, you just have to write on a unique line the path to the file or folder you want to ignore (relative to the root of your project).

#### for a file

```
/path/to/file.ext
```

#### for a folder and all its content

```
/path/to/folder/*
```

Then, to remove ignored files on the remote, type in a terminal:

```
cd root/of/your/project
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'update .gitignore'
```

You should now be able to push. Feel free to customize the commit message.

Answer (score 4):

If you created a new commit which removed the large files, this will not help the filesize limit problem, because they are still in your history. I would recommend rewriting your history to not have the large files in them.

One way you can do this is with `git rebase -i` and squash the commit that added the large file and the one that removed it.

If you have literally *just started tracking history* with `git`, you could simply blow away your repository with `rm -f .git` and then reinitialize with `git init .`, this time not adding the large files in the first place.

Comment: How would I skip adding the Pod folder? sorry, I am new to this

Comment: @mick1996. One way is to add `/Pod` to a file called `.gitignore` and use `git add .`. Another way is to manually specify every top level directory and file in the `git add` command: `git add <file1> <file2> <dir1> <dir2>...`.